# Call SSIS package using SQL Server Login

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm attempting to initiate an ETL procedure from a .NET application with components in both SQL and SSIS. I have no influence over the .NET application other than to create a button that calls a stored procedure (including passing in parameters). The application requires a SQL Server login to connect to the database.

The problem that I have is that I cannot initiate an SSIS package using a SQL Login (needs a Windows login) and the application cannot work with a Windows login (needs a SQL login). How do I square this circle?

**More detail**

The application is managing dozens of warehouse dimensions, each using its own ETL process. The code is designed that you pass a Table_ID into a stored procedure and that procedure creates and starts the SSIS execution to run the import. The rest of the ETL is then done in SQL. A vastly simplified dynamic SQL script would then look something like that below, with the output of the dynamic SQL shown under that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Core].[Execute_Dimension] (@Dimension_Table_ID int) AS

-----------------------------------------
--DECLARE @Dimension_Table_ID INT  = 2001
-----------------------------------------

/************************************************
Declare variables to work with
************************************************/
DECLARE @Dimension_Table_Name   nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @SSIS_Project_Name      nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @sql_import             nvarchar(max) = N''
DECLARE @sql_transform          nvarchar(max) = N''
DECLARE @sql                    nvarchar(max)

SELECT  @Dimension_Table_Name           = [Dimension_Table_Name],
        @SSIS_Project_Name              = [SSIS_Project_Name]
FROM    [Core].[View_Dimension_Table]
WHERE   [Dimension_Table_ID] = @Dimension_Table_ID

/************************************************
Import
************************************************/
SET @sql_import = CONCAT(N'
-- ====================================================================================
-- Description:     Import Process

BEGIN TRY
    -----------------------------------------
    DECLARE @execution_id bigint
    DECLARE @SSISStatus int

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution]                  @package_name       = N''',@Dimension_Table_Name,N'_',@Dimension_Table_ID,N'.dtsx'',
                                                                @execution_id       = @execution_id OUTPUT,
                                                                @folder_name        = N''Trinity'',
                                                                @project_name       = N''',@SSIS_Project_Name,N''',
                                                                @use32bitruntime    = ''FALSE'',
                                                                @reference_id       = Null

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]     @execution_id,
                                                                @object_type        = 50,
                                                                @parameter_name     = N''SYNCHRONIZED'',
                                                                @parameter_value    = 1

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution]                   @execution_id

    --Execution has failed if SSISDB status <> 7
    SELECT @SSISStatus = [Status] FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions] WHERE [execution_id] = @execution_id

    -----------------------------------------
    IF @SSISStatus = 7
    BEGIN
        PRINT ''Import: Has Succeeded''
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT ''Import: Has Failed''
    END
END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ''Import: Has Failed''
    END CATCH
')

/************************************************
Transform
************************************************/
SET @sql_transform = CONCAT(N'
-- ====================================================================================
-- Description:     Transform Process

BEGIN TRY
    -----------------------------------------
    EXEC [Transform].[Proc_',@Dimension_Table_Name,N'_Transform]
    -----------------------------------------
    PRINT ''Transform: Has Succeeded''
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ''Transform: Has Failed''
END CATCH

')

/************************************************
Package completed
************************************************/

SET @sql = CONCAT(  @sql_import,
                    @sql_transform
                    )

EXEC (@sql)
```

Give an output such as that below:

```
-- ====================================================================================
-- Description:     Import Process

BEGIN TRY
    -----------------------------------------
    DECLARE @execution_id bigint
    DECLARE @SSISStatus int

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution]                  @package_name       = N'ActiveDirectoryUser_2001.dtsx',
                                                                @execution_id       = @execution_id OUTPUT,
                                                                @folder_name        = N'Trinity',
                                                                @project_name       = N'DataMart_ICT',
                                                                @use32bitruntime    = 'FALSE',
                                                                @reference_id       = Null

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]     @execution_id,
                                                                @object_type        = 50,
                                                                @parameter_name     = N'SYNCHRONIZED',
                                                                @parameter_value    = 1

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution]                   @execution_id

    --Execution has failed if SSISDB status <> 7
    SELECT @SSISStatus = [Status] FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions] WHERE [execution_id] = @execution_id

    -----------------------------------------
    IF @SSISStatus = 7
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Import: Has Succeeded'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Import: Has Failed'
    END
END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'Import: Has Failed'
    END CATCH

-- ====================================================================================
-- Description:     Transform Process

BEGIN TRY
    -----------------------------------------
    EXEC [Transform].[Proc_ActiveDirectoryUser_Transform]
    -----------------------------------------
    PRINT 'Transform: Has Succeeded'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Transform: Has Failed'
END CATCH
```

Comment: As youv'e found out, you can't start an SSIS package using a SQL Login. What you could do, instead, is start an Agent Job (and then the Agent Service Account would run the package), or you will need to use a connection that uses a Trusted Connection.

Comment: I'm curious - what does "I cannot initiate an SSIS package using a SQL Login (needs a Windows login) " mean - do you get an error when you try it? I would assume the process would run under the SQL Server service account or the SQL Agent account or maybe even some kind of SSIS service account

Comment: Oh: here it is: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1860473/Executing-an-SSIS-Task-from-a-SQL-Authentication-Login Can I suggest next time you post the error message.

Comment: Reading around.. it seems like the best option is to create a queue. The button puts a request on the queue and a SQL Agent job picks it up and runs it. Regardless you need to nominate a windows service account that does this work.

Answer (score 1):

It's should be possible to run script behalf of another user or group according to the explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql). shortly explained it has to look like this:

1. add `IMPERSONATE` grant
2. map Windows and SQL server logins on DB (create users)
3. try use EXECUTE as 'windows login here'
4. Execute your script
5. Do not forget to call REVERT to avoid any contingencies and unauthorized access

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses. However, I've not had any success when trying to implement them, specifically around the SSIS element of the script.

I run the following...

```
--[domain/windowsuser] has sysadmin server role, but no explicit user asigned to individual databases

USE [DataMart_ICT]

CREATE USER [domain/windowsuser] FOR LOGIN [domain/windowsuser]
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [domain/windowsuser]

CREATE USER [DBF_App_Admin] FOR LOGIN [DBF_App_Admin]
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [DBF_App_Admin]

GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::[domain/windowsuser] TO [DBF_App_Admin]
```

... attempt to run this subsection of the code I presented earlier (the bit that's causing the problems)...

```
USE [DataMart_ICT]
GO

    EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'domain/windowsuser'

        -----------------------------------------
        DECLARE @execution_id bigint
        DECLARE @SSISStatus int

        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution]                  @package_name       = N'ActiveDirectoryUser_2001.dtsx',
                                                                    @execution_id       = @execution_id OUTPUT,
                                                                    @folder_name        = N'Trinity',
                                                                    @project_name       = N'DataMart_ICT',
                                                                    @use32bitruntime    = 'FALSE',
                                                                    @reference_id       = Null

        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]     @execution_id,
                                                                    @object_type        = 50,
                                                                    @parameter_name     = N'SYNCHRONIZED',
                                                                    @parameter_value    = 1

        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution]                   @execution_id

        --Execution has failed if SSISDB status <> 7
        SELECT @SSISStatus = [Status] FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions] WHERE [execution_id] = @execution_id

USE [DataMart_ICT]
GO
REVERT
```

... and get the following error:

```
The current security context cannot be reverted. Please switch to the original database where 'Execute As' was called and try it again.
```

The problem seems to be with EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution]. If I comment out this line it works. Looking at this (MS Built and defined) procedure, it already contains its own EXECUTE AS and REVERT, and I obviously can't change this.

I get a similar issue if I call [msdb].[dbo].[sp_start_job], which I would need if I were to call a SQL job that initiated the SSIS package.